# display javascript result with php if condition

Tags: javascript, php

we are using below script to display results for **both** types : **admin & designer**

**script**

```
var colsOption = [  
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"15",renderer : my_renderId},   
    {id: 'created_at' , header: "Order Date" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'entity_id' , header: "Order Id" , width :"75"},
    {id: 'product_id' , header: "Product Id" , width :"70"},
    {id: 'designer_id' , header: "Designer" , width :"110"},
];
```

[image]

now we want to display "Designer" column only for **type = admin** so we are trying to display javascript result with php if condition as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057317/run-a-javascript-function-from-a-php-if-statement)

**php**

```
if ($accountType == "admin"){
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var colsOption = [    
              {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'15',renderer : my_renderId},   
              {id: 'created_at' , header: 'Order Date' , width :'120'},
              {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'75'},
              {id: 'product_id' , header: 'Product Id' , width :'70'},
              {id: 'designer_id' , header: 'Designer' , width :'110'}
          ];";
    echo "</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>";
    echo "var colsOption = [    
              {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'15',renderer : my_renderId},   
              {id: 'created_at' , header: 'Order Date' , width :'120'},
              {id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'75'},
              {id: 'product_id' , header: 'Product Id' , width :'70'}    
          ];";
    echo "</script>";
}
```

but its displaying like below image. this code is reason for displaying below image `echo "<script>";` when i used  `echo "display";` still its displaying nothing....

[image]

I am new to coding & i tried lot before posting question.

Comment: have you include javascript on your project?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi yes i included `javascript` code also in orders.php file.....

Comment: use `<?php
    if ($foo == $bar) {
?>
    Lots of stuff here
    Lots of stuff here
<?php
    }
?>` this is best for readability

Comment: @iXplo thanks for suggestion, sure, i will edit question for better readability.....

Comment: I think your piece of code should work. And the output I see is not what you output. That output might come from some different place.

Comment: Does it maybe have to do with the **double-quotes** around "Designer" ?

Comment: @Cashbee that's not the issue, i updated the question with proper quotes.....

Comment: @Seb you are right, the result is coming just because of this line `echo "<script>";` when i tried `echo "display";` its displaying nothing.....

Comment: I think that problem is not in part of code you show us. It's looks like you forgot to close `quote` or wrote 2 single quotes before `null` from picture or somewhere else. Show me full php

Comment: @iXplo please check full code here : http://pastebin.com/iUXuZAPy

Comment: look at `255` line. try to make it in ONE LINE: `var __TEST_DATA__=eval('<?php echo getDesignerCollection(); ?>');` join 255 and 256 lines

Comment: @iXplo i did that, still same issue.....

Comment: and... why do U use `eval()` method in js if you can make any js code without `eval`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is in that instrument, which minificates your code.

Comment: @iXplo previous developer wrote that code, now i am working on this..... please tell how i can solve issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We made it. Code review and a little php magic made our job. It was interesting task, ty

Answer (score -1):

```
$accountType = $rows['type'];

if ($accountType == "admin")
{           

    echo "<script>";
    echo "var colsOption = [    
{id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'15',renderer : my_renderId},   
{id: 'created_at' , header: 'Order Date' , width :'120'},
{id: 'entity_id' , header: 'Order Id' , width :'75'},
{id: 'product_id' , header: 'Product Id' , width :'70'},
{id: 'designer_id' , header: "Designer" , width :'110'},


 ];";
    echo "</script>";
            }
    else
            {
            echo "worked";
            }
```