# Run JavaScript in PHP then Uncaught SyntaxError occur

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I run it without PHP then this running well.

```
      <?php 

       $it="$getuser[active]"; if($it==1)
       { echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
       echo ' $(document).ready(function () {
       var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
        // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
        title: "Welcome to my website!",
        // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
        text: "Activate Your Account Now!!<a href="active.php" target="_blank" style="color:#ffd777">Click Here</a>.",
        // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
        image: "img.jpg",
        // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just 
        sit there
        sticky: true,
        // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before 
        fading out
        time: "",
        // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
        class_name: "my-sticky-class"
    });';

       echo '  return false;
    });';
    echo '</script> ';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? The code is an unreadable mess. Just output the JS directly without using `echo`. Also 'uncaught syntax error` is half the message. The other half tells you *exactly* what the error is, and what line it's on

Comment: Hello Rory i did this with php if statement. without php it's running well

Comment: Exactly - why put it in PHP at all?

Comment: Because i check out this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057317/run-a-javascript-function-from-a-php-if-statement in this run JavaScript through PHP. in if statement.

Comment: That doesn't make it a good idea. In fact, I'd say it's a really, really bad idea.

Comment: So how to do that. because this is the notification script popup i want to done in PHP script how to do that @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape  `"`. `text: "Activate Your Account Now!!<a href="active.php" target="_blank" style="color:#ffd777">Click Here</a>.",` this line will create issue also remove line break before "sit there" and "fading out"

```
<?php 
$it="$getuser[active]"; if($it==1)
{ 
     echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
     echo ' $(document).ready(function () {
     var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
      // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
      title: "Welcome to my website!",
      // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
      text: "Activate Your Account Now!!<a href=\"active.php\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"color:#ffd777\">Click Here</a>.",
      // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
      image: "img.jpg",
      // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just  sit there
      sticky: true,
      // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
      time: "",
      // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
      class_name: "my-sticky-class"
  });';

     echo '  return false;
  });';
  echo '</script> ';
 }
 ?>
```

**EDIT**

You can skip php part also and just write script directly

```
<?php 
$it="$getuser[active]"; if($it==1)
{ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
     var unique_id = $.gritter.add({
      // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
      title: "Welcome to my website!",
      // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
      text: 'Activate Your Account Now!!<a href="active.php" target="_blank" style="color:#ffd777">Click Here</a>.',
      // (string | optional) the image to display on the left
      image: "img.jpg",
      // (bool | optional) if you want it to fade out on its own or just  sit there
      sticky: true,
      // (int | optional) the time you want it to be alive for before fading out
      time: "",
      // (string | optional) the class name you want to apply to that specific message
      class_name: "my-sticky-class"
  });

     return false;
  });
  </script>
 <?php }
 ?>
```

Comment: Awesome work like a charm. Exactly what i want Thanks