# How do you type php variables in js code?

Tags: javascript, php, sql

So, I want to show a js alert to the user if they exist in a table called paymentindue. The table has a custom message column. I want the alert to show the custom message. I am using PHP to handle sql queries

```
    <?php 
include 'dbconn.php';
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$email = $_SESSION['email'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where email='$email' AND username = '$name'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            echo '<script>alert("<?php Custom message goes here?>")</script>';
        }
?>
```

But the problem is that I get the alert  instead of the custom message

Comment: Can refer to the suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057317/run-a-javascript-function-from-a-php-if-statement

Comment: Try this `<script type="text/javascript">
      let message;        
      message = "'.$phpvariable'"
      alert(message);
 </script>';`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085648/how-to-escape-string-from-php-for-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split your echo into two strings and a php variable to make this work.

```
$your_custom_message = 'Your message here'
echo '<script>alert("' . $your_custom_message . '")</script>'`
```

Comment: That won't work. You are sending raw php to the user.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to send php code to the user, which doesn't work. Instead, just compose the message in your script if needed.

```
$message = "something you compose here";
echo '<script>alert("'. $message .'")</script>';
```